# macOS: Ping no response but ping6 working

Tags: networking, macos, ping, ipv6, ipv4

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 running on macOS BigSur 11.1. The device is connected via wireless-lan to my router. The network is working with ipv4 and ipv6. The MacBook gets an ipv4 and an ipv6 address. But I can ping the MacBook only with its ipv6 address (ping6), with ping (ipv4) I got no response. From the MacBook to any other device in the network ping and ping6 is working correctly. I do not have a firewall or any other kind of security installed/active.

Do you have an idea what could be the case that only ping6 is working?

As a response to Spiff:

I'm using the whole /8, because a lot of machines and easier separation possible. Netmask 255.0.0.0. I think it is set correctly, also using DHCP. The router has 10.10.1.1, the MacBook 10.10.1.100 and the other device 10.10.10.10. What else information do you need or what could I check if correct?

ifconfig from MacBook:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 ****::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.94.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    inet6 ****::**:****:****:9a5a%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.10.1.100 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 10.255.255.255
    inet6 ****:****:****:****:****:****:****:1de4 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 ****:****:****:****:***:****:****:880b prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    inet6 ****:****:****:****::****:cb40 prefixlen 64 dynamic 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1:flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    inet6 ****::****:****:****:fe74%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether **:**:**:**:**:** 
    inet6 ****::****:****:****:fe74%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 ****::****:****:****:1510%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 ****::****:****:****:666f%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

arp from MacBook (removed a lot other devices):

```
unknown (10.10.1.1) at * on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
*-mbp (10.10.1.100) at * on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
raspberrypi (10.10.10.10) at * on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at * on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

ifconfig from other device (ping6 to MacBook possible, but not ping):

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.10  netmask 255.0.0.0  broadcast 10.255.255.255
        inet6 ****:****:****:****:****:****:****:e98b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 ****::****:****:****:e98b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **:**:**:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1778114  bytes 1652130234 (1.5 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 80938  bytes 24788533 (23.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 143565  bytes 32134689 (30.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143565  bytes 32134689 (30.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

sit0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet6 ::10.10.10.10  prefixlen 96  scopeid 0x80<compat,global>
        inet6 ::127.0.0.1  prefixlen 96  scopeid 0x90<compat,host>
        sit  txqueuelen 1000  (IPv6-in-IPv4)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

arp  from other device (removed a lot other devices):

```
*-MBP (10.10.1.100) at * [ether] on eth0
unknown (10.10.1.1) at * [ether] on eth0
? (10.10.1.255) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

Comment: Your subnet mask looks suspicious. Are you really using the whole /8 just for giggles? If it's wrong, fix it and see if that clears up the problem. If you're really using a /8, make sure you've got it set correctly everywhere, and if that still doesn't fix it, edit your Question to tell us more about your subnetting scheme. Include an `ifconfig` and `arp -a` from both of the machines.

Comment: can you ping other IPv4 addresses? Try `ping 1.1.1.1`.

Comment: `ping 1.1.1.1` is possible form MacBook and also the other device.